# Two-way SSL or One-way SSL when its one way rest call?

Tags: rest, ssl, ssl-certificate

I created a client-rest-api which calls a server-rest-api (one way post call). My client-rest-api uses certificates issued by the server-rest-api. However my client-rest-api never issued any certificates to the server-rest-api. Does it come under one-way-ssl or two-way-ssl?

Event though its just a one way call from client to server, I am thinking its two-way-ssl since here server-rest-api validates that client is having the proper certificates issued by the server?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One-way SSL authentication is if the client only verifies the certificate of the server. This validation is done to make sure that it is the expected server, i.e. no man in the middle attack.

Two-way SSL authentication (or better mutual authentication or client authentication) is if the server also verifies the certificate of the client. This is done to authenticate the client against the server using a certificate.

This means it does not matter if REST is involved it or not. It also does not matter who issued the certificates. All what matters is the communication at the TLS layer, i.e. if the server requests a client certificate and the client sends it. Since it looks like from your description that the latter is the case it is two-way SSL authentication. But I really recommend to call it "mutual authentication" or  "client authentication" because this way it is less confusing what is actually done.

Comment: My confusion stems from the fact that, I am sure server is authenticating my client, but not sure if my java client is authenticating the server. Don't I need a certificate from server and put it in my client truststore to trust that its the expected server?

Comment: @HimalayMajumdar: the client needs always to authenticate the server because otherwise man in the middle would be possible. And this authentication is almost always done with certificates. If the servers certificate is issued by a CA trusted by the client than you don't need to import the server certificate into the clients trust store the same way the browser does not know all certificates on the internet but instead only trusts the issuers CA.

Comment: In my case the server (internal to our company) currently using a self-signed certificate (internal to our company) not a CA trusted, seems like my java client (also internal to same company) is trusting the cert by default and performing 2-way ssl? Not sure if thats a good practice.

Comment: @HimalayMajumdar: Properly done the client trusts only this specific certificate because it was added as trusted to the trust store. But often this is done by simply disabling proper certificate validation in which case the application is open to man in the middle attacks. Of course I don't know how your specific application behaves.