# Does Slack support two way encryption?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am trying to figure out if Slack supports two way encryption? I can't find anything in their documentation. And then, if they do, is there a way to provide our certificate information for them to verify or do we have to use a well known CA.

And to clarify, I know Slack supports one way encryption for both types of requests:

- Me to Slack
- Slack to Me: /command or Events API

I am wondering if Slack supports two way encryption for it's APIs. This means that:

- For requests TO Slack (pushing data through a web-hook), Slack would have validate my client's certificate. And if Slack will do this, does it have to be a known CA or can I import my own root cert for validation?
- For requests FROM Slack (Events API), Slack would need to provide a certificate.

Comment: To clarify, what you are describing isn't "two way encryption", what you are describing is "mutual authentication"

Comment: IIRC, mutual encryption is often called two-way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37717125/3383907. But you're right, I should get in the habit of calling it mutual authentication.

Comment: Encryption is always "mutual".   Typically you see "symmetric" and "asymmetric" (aka Public Key) in reference to the algorithms used.  Within TLS, it uses an asymmetric algorithm (eg RSA) to share a session key for a symmetric algorithm (eg AES) for the data.    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slack does support mutual authentication with TLS. To do this, your server needs to accept certs from the [DigiCert Global Root CA](https://dl.cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt) and its intermediates, and only accept the SAN `platform-tls-client.slack.com`

You can find the Slack documentation here: https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack#mutual_tls

For general api requests going to https://slack.com/api they do not support mutual auth.  This is most likely because it means they would be doing a client certificate request to *all* users, and many libraries would do weird things with that (even if it were an optional request). They could perhaps create an alias like https://platform-tls-server.slack.com that required a certificate.

The next problem would be creating some system where the client could register a certificate with Slack so it can associate the right user (app/integration) with it.  Again, not impossible, but would require some non-trivial changes to how they manage things.

Comment: Awesome. I should have searched for mutual. Thank you. But what about mutual auth for requests from me to Slack. Slack would need to verify my client certificate. I don't see any reference for that.

Comment: No, for general API interactions they do not support mutual auth.